# Find if exists data in all related tables (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, plsql

I am looking a way to find if a data exists in all related tables. (ID_HOUSE = 1) find if 1 exists in all ID_HOUSE columns.

```
Table House    Table Bedrooms   Table Garden    and more...
ID_HOUSE       ID_HOUSE (F)     ID_HOUSE (F)
               ID_BEDR          ID_GARDEN
```

ID_HOUSE = number;
I want to know if ID_HOUSE with id 455 exists in his related tables. For example:

```
Table House    
ID_HOUSE = 455; 
exists in ID_HOUSE(table bedrooms) or ID_HOUSE(table garden) and more...???
OUTPUT: true/false  (exists in any other related tables or not)
```

My first idea was "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT and Joins WHERE ID_HOUSE= 1" but i dont know how to do it
Any help plz?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I got a few questions:
Do you want to do it in PLSQL block (stored procedure, function, trigger) or just sql query?
Do you want to do it dynamically, for example: if a new reference will be added to existing table, should it work out of the box without need of rewriting code, or is it not necessary ?
Code should return/display true if row exist in at least two tables?
Give more information if you want us to help you out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to find all related tables sometime ago, maybe could help you:

```
declare
  --
  v_exist varchar2(1);
  --
begin
  --
  for reg in (select distinct table_name
              from all_constraints
              where upper(r_owner) = upper(&owner)
              and constraint_type = 'R'
              and r_constraint_name in (select constraint_name
                                        from all_constraints
                                        where constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
                                        and upper(table_name) = upper(&origin_table)
                                        and upper(owner) = upper(&owner))
              order by table_name)
  loop
    --
    v_exist := null;
    --
    begin
      --
      execute immediate 'select 1 from ' || reg.table_name || ' ' || &v_where into v_exist;
      --
      if v_exist is not null then
        dbms_output.put_line(reg.table_name);      
      end if;
      --
    exception
      when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        null;
      when TOO_MANY_ROWS then
        dbms_output.put_line(reg.table_name);
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Table ' || reg.table_name || '; error: ' || sqlerrm);
    end;
    --
  end loop;
  --
end;
```